# Fourier transform of a Weierstraß product

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, convolution, infinite-product

Consider $E_1:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}, s\mapsto(1-s)e^s$ and the infinite (and on $\mathbb{C}$ holomorphic) product:
$$\Pi_k(s)=\prod_{q \in \mathbb{Z}^\times\setminus{k}} E_1\left(\frac sq\right)$$
Im trying to find the Fourier transform of this product. For sake of argument let us use the transform defined by:
$$\mathcal{F}[f](x)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)e^{-i \,2 \pi x \,t} dt$$
My first attempt was to use the convolution theorem that establishes a duality:
$$\mathcal{F}[f\cdot g]=\mathcal{F}[f]*\mathcal{F}[g]$$
Where $*$ denotes the convolution of functions.

We now have:
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{F}\left[\Pi_k\right]&=\mathcal{F}\left[\prod_{q \in \mathbb{Z}^\times\setminus\{k\}} E_1\left(\frac sq\right)\right]\\
&=\prod_{q\in\mathbb{Z}^\times\setminus\{k\}}^{\text{conv.}} \mathcal{F}\left[E_1\left(\frac sq\right)\right]
\end{align*}
This is where I get stuck since $E_1$ doesn't seem to have a well definied Fourier transform due to the factor $e^s$ of $E_1$. Any ideas how I should proceed? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Oh no! I swapped $\mathbb{Z}$ with $\mathbb{Q}$. I now corrected my question and the product converges absolutely due to Weierstrass. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: You meant $\prod_{q \ne 0, k}$ ? If so your function is $e^{-(s-(-1)^k)} \frac{\sin(\pi s)}{\pi s} (s-(-1)^k k)$

Comment: Which grows way too fast to have a Fourier transform in the usual sense, but it does have a Fourier transform in the sense of analytic functionals

Comment: Yes that's the index set in question, However I don't quite see why $$\prod_{z\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0;k\}} \left(1-\frac sz\right)e^{s/z}=e^{-(s-(-1)^k)}\frac{\sin(\pi s)}{\pi s} (s-(-1)^k k)$$. How would you show equality? Also I unfortunately never came in touch with analytic functionals.